# Equivalent of hardhat local node in golang

Tags: go-ethereum, hardhat, evm

I would like to know if Golang has any tools like Hardhat to simulate blockchain's environment/local node with persisting state.

I want to create an app that for a given wallet and token address simulates the transaction of buying, waiting a few blocks and then selling according to the block passed as a argument to the function (copying the state of the given blockchain). The idea is that this app should support all EVM blockchain that hardhat normally would support, so I just start the app with whatever network I want to use and then perform the transactions on that network's copy.